# String parsing using RegEx

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have string as below.

```
X:= FMLVAR("Function1", "Var1");
```

I would like parse the above string and get the 2 arguments ("Funtion1" and "Var1"). FMLVAR is function which accepts 2 strings as arguments.

At present, I am using string manipulation function such as IndexOf and substring to process the above string and strip out those arguments.

Is there any better way doing this? Possibly using regular expression.

Any advice is much appreciated.

Thanks

Alan

Comment: You can show your current code, but I guess it would be better than using REGEX.

Comment: If you're going to do this in a generic sense, it might be better to write and use a parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var s = "X:= FMLVAR(\"Function1\", \"Var1\");";

var match = new Regex(@"FMLVAR\(""(.+?)"", ""(.+?)""\);").Match(s);

var arg1 = match.Groups[1];
var arg2 = match.Groups[2];
```

Comment: Note that this does not allow to add or remove spaces.